# Meaning of “don’t silo and empower a tech savvy team”

Tags: word-usage

saw this on a slide at work. Does this mean

Don’t silo.  Empower a tech savvy team.

Or

Don’t silo.  Don’t empower a tech savvy team.

In the context it obviously refers to the first but what are language rules around this?

Comment: I'm sure you're right about the intended meaning, but the literal meaning would be closer to the second of those. I'd parse it as 'Don't silo a tech-savvy team. Don't empower a tech-savvy team' or maybe 'Don't silo then empower a tech-savvy team.'

Comment: It's missing a comma (or semicolon) between two complete sentences.

Comment: It's *terrible* grammar. It should at least be written *Don’t silo, **but** empower ...*

Comment: @WillCrawford: Not if it means what danch thinks it means; e.g., ‘‘Don’t shake and stir a martini’’, ‘‘Don’t wash and dry the dishes’’ or ‘‘Don’t salt and pepper my food’’. Of course this leaves the question: would it mean ‘’don’t do either’’ or ‘‘don’t do both’’?

Comment: I think a quick Google search for [don't silo but empower a tech-savvy team](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=don’t+silo+and+empower+a+tech+savvy+team) might be revealing - the language has been copied from other "motivational" articles online, and combined in a clumsy fashion. *Don't silo* means don't isolate the team and their data, i.e. don't "balkanise"; and *empower* seems, from what I saw, to be about allowing them to share their experience with the rest of the organisation. In other words it's a poorly punctuated tautology :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say "heard" this at work, which could be important. As written, it would generally convey the second sense, particularly if you were unfamiliar with the sense of the jargon being deployed. However one could possibly write (– I don't know, I wasn't there!) the same heard phrase as "Don't silo; and empower a tech-savvy team". This suggests to me: "select a team that is especially tech-savvy and empower them", perhaps even particularly to avoid the problems occasioned by 'siloisation'; thus giving the other meaning.